# Search in table codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I have created a table below that has name of the places as its entryPoint in the first column. I want to keep a textfield so that one can search for the place he wants to view in the table. 
How can i do this? For eg: if i type "a" in text field, all the places starting from "a" only are shown in the table.

json value for table

```
connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
            @Override
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                    JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                    results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    responseInout = (Vector) results.get("inout");
    for (int i = 0; i < responseInout.size(); i++) {
                Hashtable hash = (Hashtable) responseInout.get(i);
                String entryPoint = (String) hash.get("entry_point");
                String passengerIn = (String) hash.get("passenger_in");
                String passengerOut = (String) hash.get("passenger_out");
                String vehicleIn = (String) hash.get("vehicle_in");
                String vehicleOut = (String) hash.get("vehicle_out");
                dataInOut[i][0] = entryPoint;
                dataInOut[i][1] = passengerIn;
                dataInOut[i][2] = passengerOut;
                dataInOut[i][3] = vehicleIn;
                dataInOut[i][4] = vehicleOut;
            }
        }
 connectionRequest.setPost(false);
    connectionRequest.setUrl("http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/reports/getReports/2015-12-30");
        connectionRequest.setDuplicateSupported(true);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);
```

//table

```
Table table = new MyTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNamesInOut, dataInOut));
```

//what to do here in textField

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {

                String searchPlace = tf.getText();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two types of "search":

- Data narrowing - this will hide the rows where the text doesn't show.
- Highlight - this will highlight the cells where the data appears

If you choose the data narrowing route just create a new model without the rows that don't contain the data you want and invoke: `table.setModel(searchModel);` this will leave only the search results.

If you want the highlighting mode In the search field just call `table.setModel(table.getModel());` this will force the table to rebuild.

Then override in the table:

```
protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
    Component c = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
    if(isSearchedValue(value)) {
        c.setUIID("SearchResult");
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then style SearchResult to be the highlight color you want and all is well...